# How does CPU know how much time a process take to complete?

Tags: operating-system

I studying various CPU scheduling algorithm in OS, I was asked this question once I was not able to answer it. Can anyone explain me?

Comment: It,does not, and can not, know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS can compute the total needed time for each task, by means of first calculating its CPI (cycles per instruction). There is a weighted average CPI for each job. I hope this answers the question. But if you are talking about burst time then there is a default value to those unknown processes.